Calling an Alexa skill from a custom skill
How can one initiate a generic Alexa skill from within a custom Alexa skill coded in python?  In this case, the generic Alexa skill will be called once certain conditions are met in the custom skill.  Seems like this should be simple to do, but cannot find examples or documentation.
I am working to accomplish this with a routine, but cannot conditionally engage a skill based on feedback from target participant.
